# Golang language package returns tag "pt-u-rg-brzzzz" for "pt-BR"

Tags: go, internationalization

Following along with the [Go.dev blog post on matching languages](https://go.dev/blog/matchlang), When trying to match a user preferred language of "pt-BR" to a list of server languages ("en", "pt", "es"), Go returns a language tag with a tag.String() value of "pt-u-rg-brzzzz".  Any ideas why this is the case?  I was expecting simply "pt" (and my Go test files from six years ago were expecting "pt" as well).

Go Playground Example: https://go.dev/play/p/CVAy8t8Z0X5